# Como obtener sólo los números de un String con palabras y números en Java

Tags: java

**Problema**

Me interesaría coger solo los números de una cadena, y ponerlos en *int* separados

**Ejemplo**

Por ejemplo, si yo pongo un `Scanner.nextLine()`, y esa línea es:

String a :   Metros de tierras en Valencia y precio: 500, 10000.

String b :   Metros de tierras en Asturias y precio: 100, 2000.

**Que he intentado**

Había pensado en utilizar un `StringTokenizer` con los espacios, o con el (:). Pero no acabo de entenderlo.

Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Puedes probar a utilizar la clase replaceAll() de java , puedes remplazar todas las letras por "" y así luego eliminar los espacios en blanco  con la clase trim(). Así te quedarían solo los números.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo hacer algo como esto:

```
List<Integer> extraerNumeros(String cadena) {
      List<Integer> todosLosNumeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      Matcher encuentrador = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(cadena);
      while (encuentrador.find()) { 
        todosLosNumeros.add(Integer.parseInt(encuentrador.group()));
      } 
      return todosLosNumeros;
 }
```

Explicación:

- En el código estoy usando expresiones regulares, en concreto `\d+` que me permite encontrar dígitos consecutivos
- recorro todas las veces que se encuentre una cadena que satisfaga la expresión regular
- para cada subcadena que concuerde la convierto a numero entero
- guardo el numero que hallé en una lista

Puedes hallar un ejemplo interactivo en [DEW](http://dew.apidesign.org/dew/#ab28a67c4b4fbee3f1beeb39e6116279)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función isDigit() de la clase Character. El bucle recorre el String caraceter a carácter y comprueba si el carácter es un entero. Luego, lo almacena en un arrayList. Puedes recuperarlos con la función lista.get(i).

Para coger solo enteros:

```
String cadena = "cadena101";
            ArrayList<Character> lista = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i< cadena.length(); i ++)
            {
                if(Character.isDigit(cadena.charAt(i)))
                    lista.add(cadena.charAt(i));

            }
```

Para mostrar los resultados:

```
for(int j = 0; i< lista.size();j ++)
{
      System.out.println(lista.get(j);                    
}
```

Comment: Este método sirve únicamente para números de un dígito, pues daría como resultado tres números 1,0,1 en vez del entero 101.